# EWS Managed API: Bulk Create operation?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using EWS Managed API 1.2. Is it possible to do a bulk operation( Create, Delete, MarkComplete) for tasks or other items using the managed API? I can do it using EWS directly, but cannot find any method to perform CRUD on multiple items using the managed API. (no loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch methods on the EWS Managed API are located on the ExchangeService object. CreateItems(), DeleteItems(), BindToItems(), and UpdateItems() methods are what you want.

With regards,

Michael Mainer (Microsoft)